# Azure/BitBucket continuous deployment not working for merges

Tags: git, azure, merge, bitbucket

I'm trying to set up continuous deployment from BitBucket Git to Azure. When I commit and push to my master branch the site redeploys in a couple seconds and works perfectly, but what I want is to develop on the dev branch, merge with the master branch, and then push the master branch to Git. For some reason pushing the merge doesn't trigger the automatic deployment.

If I open the Azure portal and click the "Sync" button after a merge, it will find the change and redeploy, but it doesn't happen automatically.

Can anyone sugges a fix, or (if not) an alternate workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `--no-ff` flag to your merge. Azure might only pick up merges which haven't been performed with a fast forward. Using the no fast forward flag will create a new commit for your merge. This works for me when merging from another branch to master.